# Get value from html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this.

```
<form id="myform">
   <table>
     <tr><th>TEST</th> <th>VALUES</th> <th>UNIT</th>
     <tr><td>Abc</td><td><input type="text" ></td><td>unit 1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>DEF</td><td><input type="text" ></td><td>unit 12</td></tr>
     <tr><td>ASD</td><td><input type="text" ></td><td>unit 321</td></tr>
   </table>
         <input type="button" id="btn" value="click" />
 </form>
```

I'm getting those value which is not null from the form `#myform`. I'm using jquery, Here is code.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
          var store = [];
          var i = 0;
     $('#myform :input[type="text"]').each(function(){
       var testVal = $(this).val();
       if(testVal != null){
        store[i] = testVal;
         i++;
          }
   });
 });
```

This code get those values which is not null, it work good. But I want to get also `TEST` and `UNIT` value of those input fields which is not null.
FOR EXAMPLE:
   If I provide the value in second input field then it get also `DEF`, `value which is provid` and `unit 12`.
Unit is next of that input field and Test is the pervious of this.
How can I do that any suggestion, plz.
Thankx.

Comment: *"But I want to get also TEST and UNIT value of those input fields which is not null."* - So, assume an input has value but the corresponding TEST and UNIT values are null, Then how do you want to get the values for that row..? What will be the corresponding data structure..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of js objects as follows:

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var store = [];
    $('#myform :input[type="text"]').map(function () {
        var test = $(this).parent().prev().text();
        var values = $(this).val();
        var unit = $(this).parent().next().text();
        if (values) {
            store.push({
                test: test,
                value: values,
                unit: unit
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>TEST</th>
            <th>VALUES</th>
            <th>UNIT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abc</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>unit 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DEF</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>unit 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ASD</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>unit 321</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click" />
</form>
```

You can loop through the `store` array and access the values like `store[i].test` , for example.

<sub>Note that if the `test` and `unit` columns are empty, corresponding values in the object will be null</sub>